# which method can i use insted of this code(nested loops) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, methods, nested-loops

```
c1=0
c2=0
c3=0
c4=0
c5=0
c6=0
c7=0
c8=0
c9=0
c10=0
c11=0
c12=0
c13=0
c14=0
c15=0
c16=0
c17=0
c18=0
c19=0
c20=0
c21=0
c22=0
c23=0
c24=0
c25=0
'#use nested loops to check the object and count'
for i in range(1,11315):
    for j in range(1,11315):
        if df.ppinccat6[j]== '<$25,000' and df.ppeducat[i]== 'Less than high school':
            c1=c1+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '<$25,000' and df.ppeducat[i]=='High school':
            c2=c2+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '<$25,000' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Some college':
             c3=c3+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '<$25,000' and df.ppeducat[i]==" Bachelor's degree or higher ":
               c4=c4+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$25-49,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Less than high school':
              c5=c5+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$25-49,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='High school':
              c6=c6+1        
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$25-49,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Some college' :
               c7=c7+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$25-49,999' and df.ppeducat[i]==" Bachelor's degree or higher":
                c8=c8+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$50-74,999' and df.ppeducat[i]== 'Less than high school':
                c9=c9+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$50-74,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='High school':
               c10=c10+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$50-74,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Some college':
               c11=c11+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$50-74,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=="Bachelor's degree or higher":
               c12=c12+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$75-99,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Less than high school':
               c13=c13+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$75-99,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='High school':
                c14=c14+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$75-99,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Some college' :
                 c15=c15+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$75-99,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=="Bachelor's degree or higher":
                  c16=c16+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$100-149,999' and df.ppeducat[i]== 'Less than high school':
                 c17=c17+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$100-149,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='High school':
                  c18=c18+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$100-149,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Some college':
                   c19=c19+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]== '$100-149,999' and df.ppeducat[i]=="Bachelor's degree or higher":
                   c20=c20+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$150,000+' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Less than high school':
                   c21=c21+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$150,000+' and df.ppeducat[i]=='High school':
                  c22=c22+1
        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$150,000+' and df.ppeducat[i]=='Some college' :
                  c23=c23+1

        elif df.ppinccat6[j]=='$150,000+' and df.ppeducat[i]=="Bachelor's degree or higher":
                c24=c24+1
        else:
             c25=c25+1
    i=i+1
    j=j+1
```

' #print counted   '

```
print("c1=",c1,'\n',"c2=",c2,'\n',"c3=",c3,'\n',"c4=",c4,'\n',"c5=",c5,'\n',"c6=",c6,'\n',"c7=",c7,'\n',"c8=",c8,'\n',"c9=",c9,'\n',"c10=",c10,'\n',"c11=",c11,'\n',"c12=",c12,'\n',"c13=",c13,'\n',"c14=",c14,'\n',"c15=",c15,'\n',"c16=",c16,'\n',"c17=",c17,'\n',"c18=",c18,'\n',"c19=",c19,'\n',"c20=",c20,'\n',"c21=",c21,'\n',"c22=",c22,'\n',"c23=",c23,'\n',"c24=",c24,'\n',"c25=",c25)
```

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you should use a list instead of 25 `c` variables. Make that change, then you'll likely be able to automate the rest with another loop or something else. You've set things up in a way that will make your life difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested, but this should work for you:

```
df['c'] = ''  # new empty column

for (money, school, val) in [['<$25,000', 'Less than high school', 'c1'], ['<$25,000', 'High school', 'c2'] ]:  # add all your conditions
    mask = df['ppinccat6'] == money
    mask &= df['ppeducat'] == school
    df[mask]['c'] = val

df['c'].value_counts()
```

the `for` loops your conditions `money`, `school` and `val` (the value you want to assign to `c` col); `mask` is a boolean mask to your dataframe so when you do `df[mask]['c'] = val` you assign `val` only to rows which match the condition; in the end `value_counts` will count the unique values for `val` equal to c1, c2, ...